# Use "dynamic" connection pool for connecting to aurora rds serverless

Tags: connection-pooling, serverless, amazon-aurora

I have a spring boot application that run in aws as a ECS. This application use a pool of connections for connect to an instance of Aurora RDS serverless. I want to know if there are a mode to "destroy" the pool connection when there are no connection to the database. It's possible?

Thanks,
Andrea

Comment: i have the same issue, mysql connections just keep growing and RDS just increasing the capacity for idle connections, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: See my answer. let's me know if this solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for documentation. I find a resolution by use `com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource` driver and the following configuration:

```
connectionTimeout: 60000
idleTimeout: 900000
maxLifetime: 900000
minimumIdle: 0
maximumPoolSize: 10
```